# Can we wear Banalinga as pendant around our neck?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shiva-lingam, shaivism

[Banalingas or Narmada lingas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banalinga) are considered as Swayambhu Shiva Lingams which are found on the river beds of Narmada river.

There are many shops which sell them online as wearable pendants. Like this:

[image]

So, there must be many people who wear them on their body. But is it allowed in scriptures?

Which scriptures discuss the rules of wearing Banalingas and what are those rules?

AFAIK, there is a shaivite sect called [Veerashaiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingayatism) where followers do wear such Shiva Lingas as pendants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Tamil Shaivism and Kamika Agama (according to the Tevaram, Nampi Arurar), the Bana Linga is classified as Acala Linga (i.e., Lingas that should not be moved, thence, not wearable):

> The Lingas are of two kinds—cala lingas and acala lingas or Sthavara lingas—movable and immovable lingas. The cala lingas may be taken from place to place being made of metals, precious or other stones, etc. The acala or sthavara lingas, which are according to the Kamika Agama, Svayambhuva, (that which rises up by itself), the Daivika (established by the Devas), the Arsaka (established by the Rsis), Ganapatya (established by the Ganas), the Manusya (established by men) or **Bana linga —all of which are not so removed from place to place, being fixed to a place in a temple**.
> Source: [“The Religion and Philosophy of Tevaram”](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/tevaram-religion-and-philosophy/d/doc421168.html)

Comment: You may want to add "since Bana Linga must not be moved, thence it is not wearable"

Comment: I was aware of chala and achala Lingas but never knew that banalinga are of the later type . Because the manner they are formed on the river bed it is obvious that they will move along with the river's flow

Comment: But since you have reference I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: Ok :) Once I find the relevant passage in Kamika Agama I will add to answer.

Comment: Ok thank you. @GabeHiemstra